# How to Aggregate Weighted averages fields at higher level?

Tags: sql

I am calculating weighted formula for a field as `sum(revenue)/ Sum(qty)` and this is as per the below query. Now I will be creating a view that would store these results as I shown in code below.

My question is, if I select this `w_revenue` out of the view and want to see per year, how will I aggregate to show it per year?

```
select month, sum(revenue)/ Sum(qty) as w_revenue,
year
from my_revenue_table
group by month, year;

create view xyz_rev as 
Select month, sum(revenue)/ Sum(qty) as w_revenue,
year
from my_revenue_table
group by month, year;

select year, w_revenue
from 
xyz_rev ;
```

Comment: Please do not tag questions `[mysql]` and `[oracle]`. They are two different database products (albeit owned by the same corporation) and have different syntax. The difference is particularly significant with date functionality.

Comment: It's really not clear why `year, sum(w_revenue)` doesn't solve it for you. Please post some sample input data for `my_revenue_table` together with expected output derived from that sample.

Comment: @Yogesh . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You'll aggregate `W_REVENUE` once again:

```
select year, sum(w_revenue)
from xyz_rev
group by year
```

Comment: No, I cannot do that as the real requirement is to then calculate sum(revenue)/ Sum(qty) again and that will be per year.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying. Could you post an example, please? What you currently have, and what you'd want to get as a result?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no real possibility to get the `w_revenue` for the year from just knowing these values for the months i would suggest to change the view as following:

```
create view xyz_rev as 
Select month, sum(revenue)/ Sum(qty) as w_revenue,
year
from my_revenue_table
group by ROLLUP(MONTH), year;
```

This way you'll already have to year data along with the data for the single months.